# how can i store a text file into an array?

Tags: arrays

so that later i can parse the array and if the line contains 3 doubles store it into an array of object type? ill later have to store the lines with 3 doubles into another array.

here's an example of my code so far

```
    public static void readFile(){

    Scanner scnr = null;
    File info = new File("info.txt");
    try {
        scnr = new Scanner(info);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("file not found");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int counterLines = 0;
    String nextLine = "";
    while(scnr.hasNextLine()){
        nextLine = scnr.nextLine();
        counterLines ++; 

    }

    System.out.println(counterLines);

    String[] infoArray = new String[counterLines];
    for(int i = 0; i < counterLines; i++){
        infoArray[i] = scnr.nextLine();
        System.out.println(infoArray[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably spilt the text of the file into individual words using **String.split()** which gives you a **String** array.